# Not able to display a snackbar inside Appbar actions widget onPress trigger

Tags: flutter

Inside the appbar i have an actions widget- IconButton. On its onPress() i am trying to display a snackbar and after that call another function. The passed  function calls setState on main(). The snackbar doesn't show up.

If i disable the function call, the snackbar shows. I am using gloablkey to refer to encapsulating scaffold.

```
_scaffKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
         SnackBar(
                content: Text(
                   'Saved',
                 style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
               ),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
         ),
   );
   widget.setFilterState({
        "isLocal": _isLocal,
        "isPure": _isPure,
   });
```

I am setting globalkey in the sorrounding scaffold.

```
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffKey,
      appBar:...
```

I expected the snackbar to show. But there is no error either.

Comment: Maybe you should try and use Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar instead of _scaffKey.currentState.showSnackBar

Comment: Looks like Scaffold associated with `_scaffKey` is  removed from the stack when `setState` on parent widget is invoked. Try `await _scaffKey.currentState.showSnackBar(....)` then invoke next function.